# Attempt to read property "title" on null - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

when I enter the detail page in Laravel, it gives an error. I don't understand where the error is coming from. My codes are as follows.
where is the problem? actually it says it's empty, but it needs to pull data from $blog on controller side.

Controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::where('id',$id)->first();

    return view('front.detail',compact('blog'));
}
```

routes/web.php:

```
Route::prefix('{lang?}')->middleware('locale')->group(function() {

    Route::get('/', [MainController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::get('/about', [MainController::class, 'about'])->name('about');
    Route::resource('/blogs', MainController::class)->only([ 'show']);
});
```

detail.blade.php:

```
<li>
    <h2><a href="">{{$blog->title}}</a></h2>
      <p>{!! $blog->text !!}</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Check that the ID you provide in the URL has a matching database record.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a model by the main column you use `find` not `where` and the column:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::find($id);

    return view('front.detail',compact('blog'));
}
```

Then, `find` can return the Model (hence an `object`) or `null`, so in your case it is not finding the model by ID.

What you should use is `findOrFail` so it throws an exception if it did not find the model:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $blog = Blog::findOrFail($id);

    return view('front.detail',compact('blog'));
}
```

Then you can continue debugging why it is not found

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't appear you are passing the blog ID in with your URL:

```php
Route::resource('/blogs', MainController::class)->only([ 'show']);
```

Try changing your route to this:

```php
Route::resource('/blogs/{id}', MainController::class)->only([ 'show']);
```

Your URL should be something like (where 5 is the blog ID):

```
http://yourdomain.com/blogs/5
```

You could also use binding:

```php
// Route
Route::get('/blogs/{blog}', [MainController::class, 'show']);

public function show(Blog $blog)
{
    return view('front.detail', ['blog' => $blog]);
}
```

More info can be found here:
[Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: You might want to read up on [resource controllers and actions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) which Laravel creates for you when using the resource route helper. It automatically configures route model binding too so you don’t have to.

Comment: Appreciate the point in that direction. I'll give it a read. Did you have a solution to the OP's problem? You might be able to help us both out.

Comment: I suspect this is a [picnic problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error) and that the ID being provided doesn’t have a matching database record.